# Sequelize won't close after bulkcreate

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm just getting started on Sequelize to write to a MSSQL db - all working well, but my node program never finishes and returns to the terminal. Code looks like this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(...);
const JournalLine = sequelize.define('journalLine', {...});
JournalLine.sync().then(() => {
   JournalLine.bulkCreate([...])
});
```

Is there something I need to close off in order to end the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provided `callback` function or utilise `Promise`, following will work

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(...);
const JournalLine = sequelize.define('journalLine', {...});
JournalLine.sync().then(() => {
   return JournalLine.bulkCreate([...]).then( result => {
     console.log('done');
     return result;
   })
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this was right, and also revealed really badly written code elsewhere - an afternoon wrestling with writing and calling Promises correctly, and it's all working solidly. Also, I needed to add a sequelize.close() call